# NetLogo: How to find out if a value has changed

Tags: variables, netlogo

I have a method that has to find out if the variable has changed before the next procedure can begin. Is there a simple way to find out if a variable has change? Something like below.

if variable-name has changed? [perform-code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this, but it's pretty easy to do yourself. If you only need to keep track of one value, then you can do something like:

```
globals [ my-variable last-my-variable ]

to do-stuff
  if my-variable != last-my-variable [
    set last-my-variable my-variable
    perform-code
  ]
end
```

The same technique can be applied to agent variables as well.